# ¿Cómo conectar un sistema en C# con una base de datos MySQL fuera de la red LAN?

Tags: c#, mysql, mysql-workbench

se como hacerlo de manera local pero no se como se realiza la conexión fuera de la red usando de servidor mi PC

Comment: Tienes como saber la ip del servidor que tiene instalado mysql?

Comment: Si te refieres ala ip privada si, tengo instalado mysql en una pc normal

Comment: Yo te recomendaría nunca tener accesible una base de datos al exterior (internet). En estos casos, la opción mas recomendable es crear un webservice que sirva de puente entre la aplicación y la Base de Datos.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normalmente cuando te conectas a un servidor `LOCAL` el nombre del servidor puede ser:

```
localhost
(local)
.//un punto solamente
NOMBREDELAPC
```

Cuando te conectas a un `server` en red local las conexiones son exactamente iguales, solo debes cambiar el nombre LOCAL por el nombre o la IP del servidor ejemplo:

```
servidorMySQL
192.168.1.15
```

Para validar que tienes acceso al servidor puedes hacer un `ping` en `cmd`, e intentar conectarte con el administrador de base de datos al servidor.

Otra cosa importante es que debes saber el usuario y la contraseña con la que te conectaras.

Te anexo ejemplos de cadena de conexión:

**Servidor LOCAL**

```
//Conectandote al servidor local
MySqlConnection conexion = new MySqlConnection();
conexion.ConnectionString = "Server=localhost;Database=Nombre_de_la_base_de_datos; Uid=Nombre_de_usuario_local;Pwd=contraseña_local;";
conexion.Open();
```

**Server en la red**

```
//Conectandote a un servidor de la red lan suponiendo que la ip del servidor es 192.168.1.15
MySqlConnection conexion = new MySqlConnection();
conexion.ConnectionString = "Server=192.168.1.15;Database=Nombre_de_la_base_de_datos; Uid=Nombre_de_usuario_del_servidor;Pwd=contraseña_del_servidor;";
conexion.Open();
```

**Si tu servidor esta en la red local**

Basta con la ip o nombre del servidor, obvio darle los permisos al firewall para el puerto que utiliza el servidor de BD

**Si tu servidor es de un proveedor de internet**

Es igual, el proveedor te va dar un nombre de servidor algo como:

servidor2354.proveedor.com

igual con usuario y una contraseña

**Si lo que quieres es un server LOCAL publicarlo para utilizarlo con internet**

Como mencionas si es necesaria la IP publica, con eso te podrias conectar y abrir los puertos correspondientes para salir y aceptar conexiones, si tu ip publica es dinamica puedes utilizar un servicio tipo NOIP o dynDNS para tener un nombre como miserver.dyndns.net que este apuntando a la ip publica de tu server y se actualice automaticamente cada vez que cambie, otra cosa que se puede hacer es comprar servicio de IP FIJA

**Con VPN**
Otra opción que tienes es crear un VPN, obviamente necesitas internet en ambos sitios, server y cliente, y puedes crear VPNs ya sea con hardware o con software, CISCO es uno de los mayores proveedores, pero también tu compañía de internet debería poderte dar ese servicio, se paga una renta mensual como pagar el internet por una conexión de tipo VPN, es como si las computadoras estuvieran locales, pero utilizan el enlace de internet.

**Conclusion**

Si es un proyecto escolar o personal y no quieres gastar dinero, utilizar un servicio [NoIP](https://www.noip.com/) gratis he investiga como abrir los puertos del firewall y exponer el servidor, debes tener internet.

Si es para conectar sucursales de una empresa utiliza las VPNS y paga por el servicio.

Si es para publicar un sitio web en internet, renta el servidor de base de datos a algún proveedor como amazon web services por ejemplo.

Comment: Pero conectarse de este modo solo con la ip privada solo sirve para conectar en un servidor dentro de una red lan no? No necesitaría en algún punto la ip publica que proporciona el provedor de internet?

Comment: amplié un poco la respuesta, ¿Que quieres hacer exactamente?

Comment: Perdón, ya leí que dices FUERA de la red LAN, mas bien quieres decir en INTERNET o en redes WAN